# How to forward messages from a stream to a broadcast channel?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to build a stream that should send its elements to two other streams, that are to be executed in parallel. I tried creating a broadcast channel with:

```
let (int_sender, int_receiver) = broadcast::channel(DEFAULT_CHANNEL_CAPACITY);
```

and then doing `stream.forward(int_sender)`, with two more streams built from the `int_receiver`, but it doesn't work because `broadcast::Sender` doesn't implement `Sink` (unlike `mpsc::Sender`). Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

`forward` is just a convenience method for connecting a stream to a sink. You can implement the same functionality manually with code like the following:

```
while let Some(item) = stream.next().await {
    int_sender.send(item)?;
}
```

Comment: I'm building the stream declaratively - the fn that is building the stream is not `async`, it just receives the `Receiver` for the `Source` and a `Sender` for the `Sink`. It is responsible for everything in between, but the stream itself is launched externally

Comment: @roman-roman You can use [`try_for_each`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/prelude/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#method.try_for_each) to similar effect, creating a future that forwards messages to the channel without needing the destination to be a `Sink`.

Comment: @roman-roman you probably could just use `tokio::spawn(async move { ... })` with the code above to create a task that will continue forwarding items from the stream to the channel in the background